# Join two tables in Neo4j, noSQL

Tags: sql, neo4j, nosql

The query which I wanted to resolve is :

> "List of patients in Diabetes category who have been coming to the hospital for more than 2 years "

There are two tables, "PATIENTS_INFO" and "HOSPITAL_INFO" both have a common attribute, "PATIENT_ID"

I tried this query but it didn't work:

```
MATCH (p:PATIENTS_INFO)->(h:HOSPITAL_INFO) WHERE p.years > 2 AND h.Category = 'Diabetes'RETURN p;
```

Could someone help me out to join the two table and solve this query?

Comment: is it normal that you are speaking about `tables` ? Or you want to say `label` ?  Your query give you something or not (an error, or zero result) ?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about basic Cypher syntax. Stack Overflow isn't generally meant for basic questions that can be answered by easily accessible documentation. Please start with the [Cypher documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/), and you can always use the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) for quick reference.

Comment: I think you need to provide a representative data sample if you want to obtain some meaningful help

Answer (score 0):

Your schema needs more complexity. You have nodes for patients and hospitals. It sounds like you need at least one additional node, such as visit or admission. It might be visit with properties of ID, date, visit_type (out-patient or inpatient) and diagnosis. You also need edges/relationships between these nodes, for example:
(p:Patient)-[pv:PatientVisit]-(v:Visit)-[hv:HospVisit]->(h:Hospital)

Then you could query like this:

```
match  (p:Patient{ID:xxx})-[pv:PatientVisit]-(v:Visit)-[:HospVisit]->(h:Hospital) 
 with p where min(v.date)<**** 
 with p,collect(v.ID) as VIDs
match (p:Patient{ID:xxx})-[pv:PatientVisit]-(v:Visit)-[:HospVisit]->(h:Hospital)
 where v.ID in VIDs and v.diagnosis='Diabetes'
return p,v,h
```

***There are several ways to handle the date differences, APOC function being perhaps the best.

The initial match finds all the patient visits for patients who had a two year relationship with any given hospital and collects the visitIDs. The second gets all their visits and the hospitals for these.

You can modify this if you only want list of patients and not all the details.

You should consider using standard code sets for diagnoses, such as ICD10-CM or SNOMED. Also hospital identifiers such as NPIs. You may want to look at the AHRQ standard datasets for hospital admissions to see how they handle the complexity of these data: https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/nisoverview.jsp